# Как передать value селекта в скрипте ajaxupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

Проблема вот в чем, есть ajax upload загрузка файлов, все работает, но хочу вместе с файлом передать и value селекта в **postData:**, пробовал и так и сяк, не получается, как правильно сделать, посоветуйте,
вот селект и скрипт загрузки
передает только тот селект который был выбран при загрузке страницы

```js
$('document').ready(function ($, data) {
  
    $('.upload').upload({
        action: '/admin/upload',
        label: 'Перетащите файл или кликните для выбора',
        postKey: 'newfile',
        maxQueue: 1,
        postData: ({data: data = $('#my_select').val()}),
        maxSize: 300485760
    }).on("start.upload", Start)
            .on("filestart.upload", fileStart)
            .on("fileprogress.upload", fileProgress)
            .on("filecomplete.upload", filePComplelele)
            .on("fileerror.upload", fileError)
            .on("complete.upload", Complete);
});
```

```html
<select id="my_select">
     <option value="1">Список 1<option>
     <option value="2">Список 2<option>
     <option value="3">Список 3<option>
     <option value="4">Список 4<option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$('#my_select option:selected').val()` ?

Comment: тоже самое, передает ток который при загрузке был выбран, а не тот который я выбираю ((

Comment: ну так и отправляйте после выбора, а не загрузки документа.

Comment: попробуйте вынести data = $('#my_select').val() до инициализации upload, а потом передать уже переменную в postData

Comment: пробовал и так, тоже самое, 
 
нужно как то через change() только как

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему скрипту, запрос upload как раз и отправляется при загрузке страницы. А на этот момент вполне логично, что по вашему селектору как раз и возвращается select, установленный при загрузке.

Вызов upload необходимо привязать к чему то типа button click, и внутри обработчика вычислять:

```
$('#my_select').val();
```